# Where to handle event of UIApplication subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication

While studying UIApplication, I find a way to add a view on top of all UIViewController.

```
  UIView *testView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,40,250,250)];
    [testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:testView];
```

It is displaying correctly.

I am wondering if I created a menu with some buttons instead of testView. Where can i handle those events in **AppDelegate or Current ViewController**

`If it is possible` then tell me how to `change text of any ViewController` on clicking menu button.

I mean how to get the **context of another ViewController** and set its View Property from that button.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You can add button and set it's action events. Then you may add Observer using `NSNotificationCenter`. Then you can receive notification about the button click in whichever `UIViewController` you want.

Here is the code:

add button like this:

```
UIButton *button =  [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,40,250,250)];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:button];
[button addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(doSomething) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Post notification in button event handler:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"buttonClicked" object:nil];
}
```

Receive the notification in another ViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourmethod) name:@"buttonClicked" object:nil];
```

Then in 'yourmethod', you can change the text.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very bad idea to add subviews to `keyWindow`, and after that retrieve current viewControllers. Probably you will make a hell. (Before iOS8 windows don't change bounds and orientations, now they change)

Instead of it, make a subclass of your root navigation controller.
Add subview's to `self.view`, and get active controller via `[self.viewControllers lastObject]`